# Fastest way to get the dimensions of a table?

Tags: sql, ssms

I am so used to python's `df.shape` which just gives you the number of rows and columns in a dataframe with no fuss.

However I am having a difficult time finding a simple way of doing this in SQL.

When I search for a solution on Stack Overflow, they either output the number of rows using `count(*)` or output the number of columns using `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]`.

I have never seen an output with both dimensions.

I have hacked this together, testing on my table `Employee_Location`:

```
SELECT count(*) as Dims
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE table_name = 'Employee_Location'
union
select count(*) from Employee_Location;
```

Which outputs:

```
Dims
7
314636
```

Is there a simpler way to get this information? Some sort of function like python/pandas `df.shape`. ?

I guess I could wrap my piece of code above in a stored procedure or function to make it easier.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, however is your output above your desired output?

Comment: I'd do `UNION ALL`, just in case.

Comment: @Stu I just wanted to know if there's already a built in way to get the dimensions of the table before I "re-invent the wheel". I guess not? And yes the output is what I'm looking for. I just need two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any built in function for this.

Although you have your data, will just offer an alternative method which will be more performant (ie doesn't actually scan the table). The `rows` count from the `partitions` table is documented as approximate although it's never been different in my experience. If your tables are partitioned then `rows` will need to us `sum`.

```
select Count(*) Cols, Max(x.rows) rows
from information_schema.columns c
cross apply (
    select rows
    from sys.tables t join sys.partitions p on p.object_id=t.object_id
    where t.name=c.TABLE_NAME and p.index_id<=1
)x
where TABLE_NAME='Employee_Location'
```